# Problems with output from exec in PHP

Tags: php, string, memory, exec

Hello I am trying to output my memory use in PHP.

My code looks like this:

```
exec('free -m', $out);
var_dump($out[1]);
list($mem, $total, $used, $free, $shared, $buffers, $cached) = explode(" ", $out[1]);
echo "Memory: " .$used. "/" . $total;
```

Now the problem is that the text prints

```
Memory: /
```

And the var_bump gives me this:

```
string(73) "Mem: 3024 1968 1055 0 159 608"
```

This string should not be (73) but (29).
If I make my own array there is no problems at all:

```
$out = array('','Mem: 3024 2020 1003 0 121 708','');
string(29) "Mem: 3024 1968 1055 0 159 608"
```

Can anyone give me a solution or a next step in debugging this?

*Best Regards,
Allan*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run `free -m`, I actually get about 73 characters (lots of spaces in there):

```
Mem:          2047          0       2047          0          0          0
```

I think you'll find that's what's causing your empty `used` and `total` values: `explode` is picking up the empty strings somewhere in those spaces between `Mem:` and `2047`.

One solution is to use [`preg_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with a separator of `"/\s+/"`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the spaces such as :

```
explode(" ", preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $out[1]));
```